# Getting HTML file from a webpage that is already opened in a browser in python 3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web

I have been looking on the internet for an answer for this but so far I haven't found quite what I was looking for. So far I'm able to open a webpage via Python webbrowser, but what I want to know is how to download the HTML file from that webpage that Python has asked the browser (firefox in this case) to open. This is because there are certain webpages with sections that I can not fully access without a certain browser extension/addon (MetaMask), as they require to also log in from within that extension, which is done automatically if I open firefox normally or with the webbrowser module. This is why requesting the HTML with an URL directly from Python with code such as this doesn't work:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.google.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
r.text
```

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen(url) as f:
   html = f.read()
```

The only solution I have got so far is to open the webpage with the webbrowser module and then use the pyautogui module, which I can use to make my PC automatically press Ctrl+S (firefox browser hotkeys to save the HTML file from the webpage I'm currently in) and then make it press enter.

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui
import time

def get_html():
    url='https://example.com/'
    webbrowser.open_new(url) #Open webpage in default browser (firefox)
    time.sleep(1.2)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.press('enter')


get_html()
```

However, I was wondering if there is a more sophisticated and efficient way that doesn't involve simulated key pressing with pyautogui.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.google.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
with open('page.html', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(r.text)
```

If the above solution doesn't work, you can use `selenium` library to open a browser:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
with open('page.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: The second one is clever, but the thing is that by opening a new browser window with webdriver, the addon/extension in which I have to log in to access the section of a certain page is not there. It opens a new browser window with no user changes, as if Firefox was just installed. Every time I used that, I would need to reinstall the add-on, so by the moment my initial solution is more efficient.

Comment: In the first solution you nee to change the typo  'opne' to open'.

Comment: None of these "work" as it depends on whether the website is scrapable or not. Many are now using bot detectors to avoid exactly this